# Xamarin Forms Access Listview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a question regarding Xamarin forms
in my shared library I have a Class called BluetoothPage.cs
wich will compiled in Ios,Droid and WinPhone.

Now in Droid shared project I want to access the Listview from the BluetoothPage.cs which is in my shared Library (Portable)

I can make it static but thats not the way we want to go 
since I want to also bind data specific for every device.

Thats why I want to access it from my .Droid shared project and also from my .IOS shared  project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Custom renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/). What you need to do is write a custom renderer for bluetooth page and then you can access the instance of the forms page from all the platforms.

### Shared Code

```
namespace BluetoothApp
{
    public ListView List {get; set;}

    public class  BluetoothPage : ContentPage
    {
    }

}
```

### iOS

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(BluetoothPage), typeof(BluetoothPageRenderer))]

namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
    public class BluetoothPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<ContentPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            var bluetoothPage = (BluetoothPage)e;

            bluetoothPage.List.DoStuff();
        }

    }

}
```

The Droid and Windows phone renderers will be slightly different but the idea is the same, you can find examples of custom renderers on the docs or [here.](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/supercharging-xamarin-forms-with-custom-renderers-part-1)

Comment: Mmm it looks like this is very much work for just a simple call ? i can use Derectives #if__ANDROID__ but than i cant use Native namespaxe Android.OS

Comment: If you want to make a call to device specific code you could use a [dependency service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/). It depends. what you are doing with the list?